# Add column to created identity table in asp.net mvc project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I use identity 2.0 in my MVC 5 project.

First time when I run the project in my DB has been created all default tables for authentication and authorization:

[image]

In AspNetUsers table I need to create additional column named LoyoutId of type integer.

My question is how can I add column to created default tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add profile data for the user by adding more properties to your `ApplicationUser` class, please visit [this](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317594) to learn more.

In your case:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public int LoyoutId { get; set; }
}
```

Then open the Package Manager Console and execute following commands:

```
PM> Enable-migrations //You don't need this as you have already done it
PM> Add-migration Give_it_a_name //This will generate a database script file
PM> Update-database //Run script file against database.
```

Now, all the new properties will turn into `AspNetUsers` table.

Comment: Also see http://www.itorian.com/2013/11/customizing-users-profile-to-add-new.html

Comment: thanks for post.what if I need to create a table and acciate  it with existing users table?

Comment: You're welcome! What do you mean? Did not help the link from my comment?

Comment: Error: "There is already an object named 'AspNetRoles' in the database"

Comment: You need to run  Add-Migration InitialMigrations -IgnoreChanges  first