# Asp .net MVC, how to query newly added column in AspNetUser table?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have added 1 additional column in `AspNetUser` table. But it seems that I can't query the new column.

I've added `Fullname` in `AspNetUser` table as shown as picture below.

[image]

**Controller**

In my controller, I can't find `fullname` in the dropdown list as shown picture below.

[image]

**Updated My Question**

[image]

Comment: Update your entity model

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: in which folder you add edmx?

Comment: i dont think i have edmx...i connect database by adding connection strings in web config

Comment: Are you sure that you have added the column to `AspNetUserRoles`? The image looks like it is added to `AspNetUsers`. You need to include the newly added columns to the ApplicationUser class.

Comment: A similar SO question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42186937/add-column-to-created-identity-table-in-asp-net-mvc-project)

Comment: The AspNetUserRoles table is accessible under Identity in MVC

Comment: Opps...i am very sorry, it is `AspNetUsers`

Comment: @Thangadurai i just updated my question and followed the link that u provided (see last picture)...but nothing happens, it still cannot query `Fullname`

Comment: In your screenshot, you have both `ApplicationDbContext` and `IdentityDbContext`. If you want to see `FullName`, use `ApplicationDbContext` instead of `IdentityDbContext` in your sample.

Comment: What is the definition of your `IdentityDbContext`? Does it specify `ApplicationUser` as the generic type parameter to override the default `IdentityUser`?

Comment: @KirkLarkin omg, i feel stupid now, i just change it now i can query, thank you very much! can you post it in the answer section so that i can vote u up?

Comment: I don't think the question will be useful to others so I think deleting it might be the best option.

Comment: maybe i will keep it for my own reference